# Amount of recoil in a 357 magnum with a 5.5 inch barrel if using a 38 special cartridge

Tags: target-shooting

I wanted a 38 special with a 4.75 inch barrel. Due to the rush on firearms and lack of mid-priced options, I purchased a 357 magnum/38 special with a 5.5 inch barrel. I have shot a 38 special with a 4.75 inch barrel before and the recoil is very manageable. Will I have that same manageability using the 357 magnum and a 38 special cartridge?

Comment: My understanding is that a longer barrel = more recoil because more powder gets burnt in the longer barrel than with a shorter barrel, but it will depend on the load I guess. - I'll wait for a more knowledgeable person to answer.

Comment: 3/4" will make a negligible difference as you may get a little extra powder burn but the added weight of the 357 frame and longer barrel will likely negate any increase in recoil. If anything i would guess you will notice a bit less.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the mass/weight of the gun. A 357 is likely to have thicker sections = more weight, so less recoil. But the longer barrel will increase recoil. It seems like it would not be much different.